# Need constraints for: Y position or height, Scrollview including Imageview

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview, swift4

It gives me the following warning: Need constraints for: Y Position or height. I can get it working with for example TextView, by disabling "Enable Scrolling" but ImageView does not have a setting for something like that. I've also tried selecting my view controller and enabling/disabling "Adjust Scroll View Insets" which gives no results.

**EDIT** Image of my hierarchy. [image]

Answer (score 3):

The layout is ambiguous, because AutoLayout does not know the height of your `UIImageView` instance. Constraining views against a `UIScrollView` is somewhat special, because the ScrollView's `contentView` needs to calculate it's size based on the subviews. To to this AutoLayout needs to be able to calculate the dimensions of all the subviews without relying on the ScrollView's size.

There are different ways to solve this.

- Add a explicit height constraint to the imageView
- Add a aspect ratio constraint to the imageView
- Set a placeholder intrinsic content size in the Interface Builder

Comment: I ended up going with setting a explicit height for now, which I'm not happy about. How would I be able to add aspect ratio constraint? Just by selecting the aspect ratio constraint checkbox? Thanks anyway tho!